# Cant return reassigned char value in java

Tags: java, if-statement, char

the question is ...
Complete the function so that it finds the average of the three scores passed to it and returns the letter value associated with that grade.

```
Numerical Score     Letter Grade
90 <= score <= 100  'A'
80 <= score < 90    'B'
70 <= score < 80    'C'
60 <= score < 70    'D'
0 <= score < 60     'F'
```

Tested values are all between 0 and 100. Theres is no need to check for negative values or values greater than 100.

```
public class GrassHopper {

    public static char getGrade(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
      int sum = s1 + s2 + s3;
      char answer = '\0';
      if(sum<=100 && sum>=90) {
        answer='A';
      } 
      else if(sum<90 && sum>=80) {
        answer='B';
      } 
      else if(sum<80 && sum>=70) {
        answer='C';
      } 
      else if(sum<70 && sum>=60) {
        answer='D';
      } 
      else if(sum>=0 && sum<60) {
        answer='F';
      }
      return answer;
    }
}
```

Checked if statement but cant see any issues with it.

I know there is a better way of doing this. But someone also tell me why the above code block doesnt work?
thanks.

Edit:

I think I did something wrong, I didnt take an average of the three values and store it in sum, will try that now.

Edit 2:

```
double sum = (s1 + s2 + s3)/3;
```

i replaced the 3 line in the code to this and now it is working.
thanks everyone

Comment: Hello and welcome. You forgot to tell us how your code doesn't work. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Also, how are you calling that method? Please [edit] your question to include a [example].

Comment: What does "doesn't work" actually mean?  I assume you know, but you're not telling us.

Comment: "_it finds the average_" - Where are you doing that step?

Comment: why not just return 'A'; ... ?

Comment: what if the sum is above 100? this seems likely your problem

Comment: yes stultuske, i will try change that now and update, thanks for the replies

Comment: Suggestion: Don't calculate an average and then store that value in a variable called `sum`. More generally, give your variables meaningful/precise/relevant names, for the sake of others who will have to read your code (and for the sake of your future self).